# Instagram api not working after going live

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I recently submitted my application for review and see that I now have basic permission and my client status is live. But now I am not receiving any data. Im getting this error:
"This client has not been approved to access this resource."

What do I need to change? I was receiving data fine before I submitted my application for review. I am just trying to receive hashtag data.

This is how I am calling the api to get a token.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id="+clientId+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&response_type=code
```

This is how I get data after token:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+hashtag+'/media/recent',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
        success: function(data){
            var images = data.data;
            $('.slider ul.images').append('<li><img    src="'+images[count].images.standard_resolution.url+'"></li>');

            setTimeout(function(){
                startSlider();
            }, 5000);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have `basic` permission, you cannot access hashtags API, with `basic` you can only get your photos.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

To get hashtags API and others that have posts from others, you will need `public_content` permission. If not you will get `This client has not been approved to access this resource` in API response

Comment: I was able to get public_content before Instagram reviewed my app. Is there a way to go back?

Comment: are u sure?, in sandbox mode?

Comment: before reviewing I was able to get my photos. But not with basic access I don't get any photos, not even my own. I keep getting that error even though I have a lot of photos with that hashtag.

Comment: what about `/users/self/media/recent` is this working ?

Comment: @ krisrak  Would I write that like this?
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/tags/'+hashtag+'/media/recent'`

Comment: no, hashtag will not work, u dont have permission, only this will work, to get your own photos: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124245/discussion-between-user5694093-and-krisrak).